# How to verify Registry key changes in GUI

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-server-2012, regedit, ansible

I am currently using Ansible to automate the updating of the registry keys of a Windows 2016 Server machine. I am able to achieve that however I have a question in regards to verifying that the registry is changed/update correctly. I usually verify the changes with the "Edit Group Policy program" or with the "Local Policy Editor", however there are some registries which does not show any changes in the Group Policy or Local Policy GUI.

-Is it possible that registry changes are not reflected in the GUI if it is not done manually on the GUI (E.g Group Policy, Local Policy)?

-If a registry key is updated correctly where else could I use to verify that it is done so other than using REGEDIT, Group Policy or Local Policy.

Just in case you are wondering the registry keys are updated/created correctly as I verified it using REGEDIT, but I require a GUI program other than REGEDIT to affirm that it is updated.

Comment: “but I require a GUI program other than REGEDIT to affirm that it is updated.” - Might help us answer your question if we understood the reason this was the case.

Comment: @Ramhound Having a GUI to confirm that the settings are updated is more of an assurance that the registry is updated correctly. This is mainly because the users of my automated script (playbook in this case) are not familiar with using Regedit and it would be great if the settings are reflected somewhere but from what I know so far some settings can be confirmed with net accounts, auditpol, etc while others may not have related commands. I am looking for a software which displays the settings similar to what the Group Policy or Local Policy editor shows. Hope that answers your question

Comment: It does not matter what a GUI indicates is the setting, if the corresponding registry key is not set, then it's not actually set.  It sounds like you need to write custom software to behave the way you need it to.  Questions seeking software recomendations are out of scope.

Comment: @Ramhound In regards to registry setting, do you happen to experience a situation where the registry is updated  but it is not reflected in the Group Policy or Local Policy editor? Just to add on, my experience so far are some registries are updated while others are simply not reflected on the UI